# Prove that $f$ has a kink

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}(2+x)^{1/3} && x<-1\\ -2/3|x|+5/3  && -1\leq x<1\\ (2-x)^{2/3} && x\geq 1\end{cases}$$
I can't prove that $x=-1$ is a **kink**.
$$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(h-1)-f(-1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{(h+1)^{1/3}+2/3-5/3}{h}=1/3$$
BUT
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h-1)-f(-1)}{h}=\frac{-2/3|h-1|+2/3}{h}=2/3$$
EDIT: am I computing the limit in the right way to arrive at the conclusion that $x=-1$ is a kink?

Comment: The constant term in the numerator should be $+2/3$, not $-2/3$

Comment: oh yes! Thank you! The first limit instead is $1/3$?

Comment: I'm not sure what definition of kink you're using, but plotting this shows that the point $x=-1$ is not interesting, but as smooth as the rest of the curve; really, it is the points $|x|=2$ at which the curve exhibits singular behaviour

Comment: kink is a point of no derivability; ex for |x| we have in $x_0=0$ a kink since $f'_-(0)=-1\neq f'_+(0)=1$.

Comment: x=-1 is a point where the function is not differentiable, not?

Comment: Yes, you have now computed it correctly. I deleted my answer because I misread the function statement